# Tic Tac Toe "Cats Game"/End Game

Tags: python, game, tic-tac-toe, turtle-graphics

I have made my first game in Python.

My program can determine when there is a winner, however I am unsure what to do if the board is full and there is NO winner (a cats game).

```
import cTurtle
import random
import sys

def DrawTicTacToeBoard(t):
    #Vertical Lines of board
    t.pensize(3)
    t.up()
    t.goto(.5,-.5)
    t.down()
    t.goto(.5,2.5)
    t.up()
    t.goto(1.5,-.5)
    t.down()
    t.goto(1.5,2.5)
    #Horizontal Lines of board
    t.up()
    t.goto(-.5,.5)
    t.down()
    t.goto(2.5,.5)
    t.up()
    t.goto(-.5,1.5)
    t.down()
    t.goto(2.5,1.5)

def flipPlayer(currentPlayer):
    if currentPlayer==0:
        currentPlayer=1
    else:
        currentPlayer=0
    return currentPlayer

def drawWhiteBox(t,x,y):
    t.up()
    t.goto(x-.25,y+.25)
    t.down()
    t.color("white")
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(.8)
        t.right(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.color("black")

def drawMarker(t,currentPlayer,markerList,move,boardLoL):
    by=int(move[0:1])
    bx=int(move[2:])
    y=by+(.22)
    x=bx-(.15)
    drawWhiteBox(t,x,y)
    t.up()
    t.goto(x,y)
    boardLoL[by][bx]=markerList[currentPlayer]
    t.write(markerList[currentPlayer],move=False,align="left",font=("Arial",48,"normal"))

def getValidMove(validMoveList,markerList,currentPlayer,boardLoL):
    move = ""
    while move not in validMoveList:
        move = input("Enter location to place your marker " + markerList[currentPlayer] + ", or EXIT to end game => ")
        if move=="EXIT":
            sys.exit()
        if move in validMoveList:
            by=int(move[0])
            bx=int(move[2:])
            if boardLoL[by][bx]=="":
                return move
            else:
                print("Location already occupied")
                move=""

def gameWon(b):
    for row in range(3):
        if b[row][0]==b[row][1] and b[row][1]==b[row][2] and b[row][0]!="":
            print("Way to go",b[row][0])
            return b[row][0]
    for column in range(3):
        if b[0][column]==b[1][column] and b[1][column]==b[2][column] and b[0][column]!="":
            print("Way to go",b[column][0])
            return b[0][column]
    for diag in range(2):
        if b[0][0]==b[1][1] and b[1][1]==b[2][2] and b[0][0]!="":
            print("Way to go",b[0][0])
            return b[0][0]
        if b[2][0]==b[1][1] and b[1][1]==b[0][2] and b[2][0]!="":
            print("Way to go",b[2][0])
            return[2][0]



    return ""

def boardIsFull(boardLoL):
    return False




def main():
    boardLoL=[["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]
    markerList=["O","X"]
    validMoveList=["0,0","0,1","0,2","1,0","1,1","1,2","2,0","2,1","2,2"]
    joe=cTurtle.Turtle()
    joe.setWorldCoordinates(-2,3,4,-1)
    joe.ht()
    currentPlayer=random.randint(0,1)
    DrawTicTacToeBoard(joe)
    move = ""
    while boardIsFull(boardLoL)==False and gameWon(boardLoL)=="" and move !="EXIT":
        move = getValidMove(validMoveList,markerList,currentPlayer,boardLoL)
        drawMarker(joe,currentPlayer,markerList,move,boardLoL)
        currentPlayer=flipPlayer(currentPlayer)
    gameWon(boardLoL)
    boardIsFull(boardLoL)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> import cTurtle
> import random
> import sys
> ```

Excellent!  Many people use wildcard imports, (`from <module> import *`), but you didn't.  You even alphabetized your imports.  Keep up the good work.

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide, has this to say in the [Function Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) section:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

That means that `DrawTicTacToeBoard` would be `draw_tic_tac_toe_board`, for example.

Your spacing does not comply with PEP 8.  Specifically:

> Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment (`=`), augmented assignment (`+=`,`-=` etc), comparisons (`==`,`<`,`>`,`!=`,`<>`,`<=`,`>=`,`in`,`not in`,`is`,`is not`), Booleans (`and`,`or`,`not`).
>
> ```
> #Vertical Lines of board
> t.pensize(3)
> t.up()
> t.goto(.5,-.5)
> t.down()
> t.goto(.5,2.5)
> t.up()
> t.goto(1.5,-.5)
> t.down()
> t.goto(1.5,2.5)
> ```

I realize that you want to save characters, but `-.5` is a little hard to read.  It almost looks like the `-` is one argument and `5` is another argument.  The extra `0` between the two would greatly improve readability.  Speaking of saving characters, you could use a `for` loop ... probably.  I haven't come up with anything that I really like, though.  You should also consider a different name for your argument.  Perhaps `turtle` would be more descriptive.

> ```
> def flipPlayer(currentPlayer):
>     if currentPlayer==0:
>         currentPlayer=1
>     else:
>         currentPlayer=0
>     return currentPlayer
> ```

This function is included in two rules mentioned above, but I mention it here because there is a much easier way to do it:

```
def flip_player(current):
    return (current + 1) % 2
```

Read more about the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator and [when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609315).

> ```
> for i in range(4):
>     t.forward(.8)
>     t.right(90)
> ```

Again, you should be using a more descriptive name, but I brought up the `for` loop because you use `i` as your variable name.  There isn't anything *wrong* with using it, but in cases where the variable is not used, it is common practice in Python to use `_` as the variable name.  It just makes it a little more obvious that it is an unused variable.

> ```
> move = input("Enter location to place your marker " + markerList[currentPlayer] + ", or EXIT to end game => ")
> ```

That line is 110 characters not including indentation.  PEP 8 says:

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

Perhaps it would be better to define a template and format it in the loop:

```
template = "Enter location to place your marker {}, or EXIT to end game => "
while move not in valid_move_list:
    move = input(template.format(marker_list[current_player]))
    ...
```

I would also change how you check your conditions in the `while` loop.  Here is what I would do:

```
while True:
    move = input(template.format(marker_list[current_player]))
    if move == "EXIT":
        sys.exit()
    elif move in valid_move_list:
        y, x = map(int, move.split())
        if not boardLoL[y][x]:
            return move
        else:
            print("Location already occupied")
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
```

There is no need for `while` to be checking anything since you account for all cases inside.  I also added an `else:` so that the user would know why he was being asked again for input.

> ```
> def gameWon(b):
>     for row in range(3):
>         if b[row][0]==b[row][1] and b[row][1]==b[row][2] and b[row][0]!="":
>             print("Way to go",b[row][0])
>             return b[row][0]
>     for column in range(3):
>         if b[0][column]==b[1][column] and b[1][column]==b[2][column] and b[0][column]!="":  
>             print("Way to go",b[column][0])
>             return b[0][column]
>     for diag in range(2):
>         if b[0][0]==b[1][1] and b[1][1]==b[2][2] and b[0][0]!="":
>             print("Way to go",b[0][0])
>             return b[0][0] 
>         if b[2][0]==b[1][1] and b[1][1]==b[0][2] and b[2][0]!="":
>             print("Way to go",b[2][0])
>             return[2][0]
> ```

You can simplify that to this:

```
def game_won(board):
    for row in board:
        if len(set(row)) == 1:
            return row[0]
    for column in zip(*board):
        if len(set(column)) == 1:
            return column[0]
    for diag in range(2):
        ...
```

I would do all of the printing outside of the function.  In your `main()` function, it would be like this:

```
print(game_won(boardLoL))
```

instead of:

```
game_won(boardLol)
```

I'm not crazy about the diagonal searching, but I can't think of anything better at the moment.  Maybe it's because I've been awake for ... *yawn*

> ```
> return[2][0]
> ```

I don't think that's what you meant.  Perhaps, `return b[2][0]`

> ```
> def boardIsFull(boardLol):
>     return False
> ```

Haven't added it yet, huh?  Maybe this:

```
def board_is_full(board):
    return all(all(row) for row in board)
```

Yeah, nifty.  You see, `all(row)` makes sure that each item in `row` is a Truthy value.  Any non-empty string is Truthy, so if any of the cells in that row is empty, `all(row)` will return `False`.  Since I am running `all()` on each of those `all()` calls, it returns `False` if any cell in the board is empty, but `True` otherwise.

> ```
> while boardIsFull(boardLoL)==False and gameWon(boardLoL)=="" and move !="EXIT":
> ```

Any condition is checking a boolean.  That is, `if ...:` is seeing if `...` is `True`.  Using `if ... == True:` is redundant because you could have just used `if ...:`.  Consequently, `if ... == False:` is redundant because you could have used `if not ...:`  You can simplify that line like this:

```
while not board_is_full(boardLoL) and not game_won(boardLoL) and move != "EXIT":
```

That line is one character too long for PEP 8.  I would suggest changing `boardLoL` to `board` in all places.  What is `LoL` doing there anyway?  Are you laughing as you type?

I hope I haven't sounded too harsh, but it's been a late night.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your program is quite good.  It is well organized and easy to understand.

### `gameWon()`

This is the buggiest function.

In one of the diagonal checks in `gameWon()`, you wrote:

> ```
> return[2][0]
> ```

… which returns `2` (treating `[2]` as a single-element list).

The `for diag in range(2)` loop is pointless: it just executes the same checks twice, for no reason.

This function has a possible side-effect of printing "Way to go *X*".  That's a bad design, since it means that you have to be careful to call it exactly once, if there is a winner.  Unfortunately, you don't take that precaution, so you'll end up printing "Way to go *X*" twice when *X* wins.

Python supports double-ended comparisons, so you can write `if b[0][0] == b[1][1] == b[2][2]`.

### `drawMarker()`

This function does more than drawing: it also updates the board.  You should either remove the board-updating code, or rename the function to `executeMove()`.  I recommend the latter.

The `move` should not be represented as a string.  If `getValidMove()`, which already parsed the string to validate the move, returned a tuple of integers `(y, x)`, then you wouldn't have to repeat that work here.

### `DrawTicTacToeBoard()`

This function is a bit tedious, and could benefit from a general routine to draw a line segment.

### `getValidMove()`

The loop structure is awkward.  See the suggested solution below.

### `flipPlayer()`

I would just write `currentPlayer = not currentPlayer`, and eliminate the function altogether.  (Note that this takes advantage of the fact that `0`/`False` and `1`/`True` are somewhat interchangeable.  Some purists might object.)

### Miscellaneous

The code doesn't follow PEP 8 conventions.  Notably:

- Function names and variable names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`.
- There should be a space before and after `=` and `==`.  There should be a space after every comma.
- The few blank lines near the end of `gameWon()` are awkward.

Avoid extreme Hungarian notation with names like `boardLoL`, `markerList`, and `validMoveList`.  It would be fine to write `board`, `MARKERS`, and `VALID_MOVES`, respectively.

When a player wins, the game exits immediately, after showing the winning board for a split second.  It would be much more satisfying to wait until the window is closed.

### Suggested solution

```
import cTurtle
import random

def draw_board(t):
    LINES = [
        ((+0.5, -0.5), (+0.5, +2.5)),   # vertical
        ((+1.5, -0.5), (+1.5, +2.5)),   # vertical
        ((-0.5, +0.5), (+2.5, +0.5)),   # horizontal
        ((-0.5, +1.5), (+2.5, +1.5)),   # horizontal
    ]
    t.pensize(3)
    for (start, end) in LINES:
        t.up()
        t.goto(*start)
        t.down()
        t.goto(*end)

def execute_move(t, board, marker, move):
    def draw_white_box(t, move):
        y, x = move
        t.up()
        t.goto(x - 0.4, y + 0.4)
        t.down()
        t.color('white')
        t.begin_fill()
        for _ in range(4):
            t.forward(0.8)
            t.right(90)
        t.end_fill()
        t.color('black')
    y, x = move
    board[y][x] = marker
    draw_white_box(t, move)
    t.up()
    t.goto(x - 0.15, y + 0.22)
    t.write(marker, move=False, align="left", font=("Arial",48,"normal"))

def get_valid_move(board, marker):
    while True:
        try:
            move = input("Enter location to place your marker {0} or EXIT to end game => ".format(marker))
            if move == "EXIT":
                return None
            y, x = map(int, move.split(',', 1))
            if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and board[y][x] == '':
                return y, x
            else:
                print("Location already occupied")
        except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
            return None
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            pass

def winner(b):
    for row in range(3):
        if '' != b[row][0] == b[row][1] == b[row][2]:
            return b[row][0]
    for column in range(3):
        if '' != b[0][column] == b[1][column] == b[2][column]:
            return b[0][column]
    if '' != b[0][0] == b[1][1] == b[2][2]:
        return b[1][1]
    if '' != b[2][0] == b[1][1] == b[0][2]:
        return b[1][1]
    return ""

def is_full(b):
    return all(b[y][x] != '' for x in [0, 1, 2] for y in [0, 1, 2])

def main():
    MARKERS = ['O', 'X']
    board = [["","",""], ["","",""], ["","",""]]
    current_player = random.randint(0,1)

    joe = cTurtle.Turtle()
    joe.setWorldCoordinates(-2, 3, 4, -1)
    joe.ht()
    draw_board(joe)

    while not winner(board):
        current_player = not current_player
        move = get_valid_move(board, MARKERS[current_player])
        if not move:
            break
        execute_move(joe, board, MARKERS[current_player], move)
        if is_full(board):
            break
    else:
        print("Way to go, {0}!".format(MARKERS[current_player]))
        input("Press the ENTER key to exit")

main()
```